# Understanding kqueue in TCP

Tags: c++, sockets, kqueue

I am following tutorials about kqueue (specifically http://eradman.com/posts/kqueue-tcp.html and https://wiki.netbsd.org/tutorials/kqueue_tutorial/), and there are parts I don't understand.  Here's my (edited) code:

```
// assume internal_socket is listening
void run_server(int internal_socket) {
    const int nchanges = 1;
    const int nevents = BACKLOG;

    struct kevent change_list[nchanges];
    struct kevent event_list[nevents];

    int kq = kqueue();

    if (kq == -1) {
        // error
    }

    EV_SET(&change_list, sock_internal, EVFILT_READ, EV_ADD, 0, 0, 0);

    while (true) {
        int nev = kevent(kq, change_list, nchanges, event_list, nevents, NULL);

        if (nev == -1) {
            // error
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nev; ++i) {
            if (event_list[i].flags & EV_EOF) {
                int fd = event_list[i].ident;
                EV_SET(&change_list, fd, EVFILT_READ, EV_DELETE, 0, 0, NULL);
                if (kevent(kq, &change_list, nchanges, NULL, 0, NULL) == -1) {
                    // error
                }
                close(fd);
            } else if (event_list[i].ident == sock_internal) {
                int fd = accept(event_list[i].ident, ...);
                // do stuff
            } else if (event_list[i].flags == EVFILT_READ) {
                int bytes_read = recv(event_list[i].ident, ...);
                // do stuff
            }
        } // for
    } // while (true)
} // func
```

I don't understand:

1. Am I right to set nevents = BACKLOG i.e. the number of concurrent connections? If not, what should nevents be?
2. Why do I check `event_list[i].flags & EV_EOF`?  My best guess is if the connection failed while the socket was sitting in the queue, then I want to remove that socket from the queue?  But why do I call kevent again?
3. In the same section as the previous point, I call `close(fd)`.  Is that correct?  The eradman tutorial has some extra witchcraft but I don't understand why.
4. If I understand correctly, kqueue could return when I am ready to read a partial message.  How do I know when the message is complete?

In case it's relevant, I'm working on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick thoughts about the code / questions:

1. No.

   There's no requirement that `BACKLOG == nevents`.

   You can pick the events out of the queue one at a time or dozens at a time, it's mostly about your preference and minimizing system calls vs. memory/stack space.

   It's also not very often that you would have all the connections simultaneously firing events... there's no real point in spending that much memory - especially when you consider large concurrency, might mean the large memory might cause cache misses and possibly incur performance penalties.
2. EV_EOF

   > Filters may set this flag to indicate filter-specific EOF condition

   Which means you must specify a filter that might raise this flag. Which filters do that? are these events you're listening for?

   You can find these in the [`man` page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2)

   One example, in sockets, is when the client disconnects the `read` capacity but leaves the `write` capacity of the socket in place. Than, the `EVFILT_WRITE` filter (if set) will invoke the EV_EOF flag.

   Personally, I think these edge cases can be checked when `write` fails instead of having an event raised.
3. calling `close` is reasonable... really depends on what you want. I might keep th connection only to read data. Or maybe invoke [`shutdown`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=shutdown&sektion=2), as it's considered more polite (but probably doesn't matter all that much these days).
4. You don't. This isn't a TCP/IP concern.

   Message wrapping should be performed by the protocol being implemented (i.e. Websockets / HTTP). Each protocol has a different message wrapping / completion design.

   The TCP/IP layer wraps packets. In the wild, these are often limited to 1500 bytes and many parts of the internet run on 576 bytes. You can google MTU for more information.

#### Side-Note:

- You probably want to add new clients to the `kqueue`.
- I would consider resetting the `nchanges` value every cycle.